# Rock paper scissors, play again?

Tags: java

For my assignment I'm supposed make the program rock paper scissors which I figured that out my main problem is I can't get the program to play again right or get the program to calculate the game scores correctly pleas help I'm going crazy trying to figure this out?!

```
//Tayler Dorsey

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PRS {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );

    public static void instructions() {
        System.out.println("This is the popular game of paper, rock, scissors. Enter your\nchoice by typing the word \"paper\", the word \"rock\" or the word\n\"scissors\". The computer will also make a choice from the three\noptions. After you have entered your choice, the winner of the\ngame will be determined according to the following rules:");
        System.out.println("Paper wraps rock (paper wins)\nRock breaks scissors (rock wins)\nScissors cuts paper (scissors wins)");
        System.out.println("If both you and the computer enter the same choice, then the game is tied.");
    }

    public static int playGame() {

        int ties = 0, wins = 0, losts = 0;

        String userchoice, computerchoice;

        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

        userchoice = keyboard.next();

        computerchoice = computerChoose();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + userchoice);

        System.out.println("Computer choose: " + computerchoice);

        if ((userchoice.equals("paper") && computerchoice.equals("paper")) || (userchoice.equals("rock") && computerchoice.equals("rock")) || (userchoice.equals("scissors") && computerchoice.equals("scissors"))) {
            System.out.println("IT'S A TIE!");
            ties++;
            return 3;
        } else if ((userchoice.equals("paper") && computerchoice.equals("rock")) || (userchoice.equals("rock") && computerchoice.equals("scissors")) || (userchoice.equals("scissors") && computerchoice.equals("paper"))) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
            wins++;
            return 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("YOU LOSE!");
            losts++;
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static String computerChoose() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        String[] answer = new String[3];
        answer[0] = "paper";
        answer[1] = "rock";
        answer[2] = "scissors";
        return answer[generator.nextInt(3)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String play;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("The Game of Paper, Rock, Scissors");
        System.out.println("Do you need instructions (y or n)?");
        String help = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (help.equals("y")) instructions();

        int result = playGame();
        System.out.println("Play again (y or n)?");
        play = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (play.equals("y"));

        else {
            int count = 0, wins = 0, losts = 0, ties = 0;
            System.out.println("Games played: " + count);
            System.out.println("Wins for you: " + wins);
            System.out.println("Wins for me: " + losts);
            System.out.println("Tied games: " + ties);
        }
        do {} while (play == "y"); {
            playGame();
            int count = 0;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is all sorts of wonky. Might want to go through and edit it appropriately (look at formatti.g on stackoverflow). I would but I'm on a phone so it's difficult.

Comment: The first step of fixing a program is to know what is wrong with it. So, what happens when you execute the program. Tell us your inputs, the expected behavior, and the observed behavior.

Comment: You forgot lizard and spock.

Comment: Basically whenever I run the program it does everything I need it to do like entering rock, paper, scissors and then the computer choosing a random answer and and such until I get to the main method and I have to get the program to ask it to play again an then it gives me all this weird stuff like that the game was played 0 times and even if i put no as for the question "Play again?" it will still make me play the game at least once more before cutting off and not even asking to play again once more after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
do {
        play = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (play.equals("y")){
}
        else {
            int count = 0, wins = 0, losts = 0, ties = 0;
            System.out.println("Games played: " + count);
            System.out.println("Wins for you: " + wins);
            System.out.println("Wins for me: " + losts);
            System.out.println("Tied games: " + ties);
        }
        } while (play.equals("y"));
```

Comment: so I tried putting that in their but I keep getting "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete statement" because of the { in if (play.equals("y")){ how do i fix that? Whenever I add more it just makes it worse

Comment: Sorry but that's a minor mistake. You are lacking a curly braces somewhere. Good luck finding it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. The code isn't inside the do-while loop, it's **after** it.
2. String equality should be checked with `equals` not with `==`.

So:

```
int count = 0;
do { // Note the code inside the do-while block
    playGame();
    count++;
} while (play.equals("y")); // Note the use of equals
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the games scores make those variable global.

```
public class PRS {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
    int ties = 0, wins = 0, losts = 0;
```

Comment: If I put that at the top of my program am I supposed delete it in the rest of my program? Because when I do get a lot of errors I don't know how to fix but when I don't it doesn't change the program at all.

Comment: Yes you are supposed to delete the other variables with the same name, now that you have them on the top you can use them everywhere.